# flutter barcode library uses mainactivity while local_auth uses fragmentedActivity, i need to use both in my app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

when I use flutter barcode library it uses  main activity while local_auth uses fragmented activity, i need to use both in my app,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }
}

Comment: import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}

Comment: that is two codes for local_auth and flutter_barocde

Comment: did you find out how to use both?